# Process Builder is not working on Windows

Tags: java, imagemagick, processbuilder

I am using Process Builder to run ImageMagick commands on Windows. For some reason, with Process Builder the output image isn't being generated most times. When I tried the same command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`, output was generated. Any idea why that is?

```
String input="D:\\Koala.jpg";
String output = "D:\\ProcessBuilderOutput\\KoalaPNG.png";
commands.add("D:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\\convert");
commands.add("-alpha off");
commands.add("-strip");
commands.add(input);
commands.add("-colorspace CMYK");
commands.add(output);
try{
    executeProcessCommand(commands);
    if(new File(output).exists() != true){ 
    System.out.println("output not generated");
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
public static void executeProcessCommand(List<String> commands) throws Exception {
    Process proc = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("-executeProcessCommand: Trying to execute :- "+commands);
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        proc = processBuilder.start();
        proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("- executeProcessCommand: Executed the command ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" - executeProcessCommand:" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if(proc != null)
                proc.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("executeProcessCommand:"+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not working consistently or not at all? What are your input files? What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: @chrylis, When I tried 10 times, output generated only one time...Anyway I have edited the question...

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and (continue to) build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Split the arguments to the ProcessBuilder. In particular split `commands.add("-alpha off");` into

```
commands.add("-alpha");
commands.add("off");
```

and similarly for `commands.add("-colorspace CMYK");`